# Is there a way to embed <script> content into a Doxygen \mainpage section?

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, doxygen

I would like to introduce some javascript `<script>xxx</script>` content into my generated index.html in order to add reddit and facebook "like" buttons to my project's main page.   Is there a way to accomplish this automatically using Doxygen?

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use @mainpage in combination with an @htmlonly...@endhtmlonly block. Here is an example:

```
/** @mainpage My Script Page

Here is an embedded script:
@htmlonly
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function displayDate()
 {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
 }
 </script>
 <div id="demo">date</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">displayDate();</script>
 <br/>
 <button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Refresh Date</button>
@endhtmlonly

*/
```

Comment: Although this answer passed a few days i just want to mention that the documentation generated could probably contain C++ like comments starting with `//!` which prevents this script from being interpreted if the code placed in between the htmlonly tags is a block sequence. Then one should use the htmlonly tag followed by a one liner containing the block to be evaluated/displayed.

Comment: @EmilKakkau I don't understand what you are trying to say. //! comments inside a \htmlonly block should be copied to the output without interpretation.

Comment: in my doc building szenario (bash+doxygen) the <script>-tag was embedded into the html code as i expected it to do. BUT all the code in between the htmlonly instruction was prefixed by //! in the generated html (output) file so the execution of the script tag was not invoked. if you need an example i will post an answer to illustrate.

Comment: or just have a look at my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602932/can-doxygen-generate-collapsable-code-sections-like-rdoc. in the documentation code i was just able to use a single line to make the <script>-tag between the htmlonly instruction work in the genereted html.